# Search for char in array

Tags: java, arrays, search, char

I'm creating a java program and am stuck on the concept of searching for a char in an array.

The code is to create a hangman game and part of it will be to display the partially completed hangman, an alphabet, and a set of blanks ("_") for the length of the word needing to be guessed. After each guess, I need to take out the letter guessed from the alphabet(this is the part I'm on right now) and if it was a right guess, replace the blank in the word with that letter or if it was a wrong guess, complete another piece of the hangman.

I've only created code to search for numbers in arrays before, not chars. I've been looking through my book and on the internet, but I can't find a solution.

Doesn't anyone know a way of doing this or where I could look to find a way?

sorry I already posted a question about this assignment, but it's due in a couple of days and I'm struggling.

Here's my code so far (the part I'm struggling with is at the very bottom):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] words =
    {
        "javascript", "declaration", "object", "program", "failing"
    };
    //generate random word from list
    Random rnd = new Random();

    String rndWord = words[rnd.nextInt(words.length)];

    //gets length of generated word
    char[] displayArray = new char[rndWord.length()];
    //displays "_" for number of chars in word
    for (int i = 0; i < rndWord.length(); i++)
    {
        displayArray[i] = '_';
    }

    char[] alphabet =
    {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
        +'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
        +'x', 'y', 'z'
    };
    String hangman
            = "Let's Play Hangman!!" + "\n"
            + "-------------" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "|" + "\n"
            + "\n" + Arrays.toString(displayArray) + "\n"
            + "       ";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hangman + " "
            + Arrays.toString(alphabet) + " ");
}

//get letter
public static char guess()
{
    String guessStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter to guess: ");

    // check if have at least one letter
    if (guessStr.length() > 0)
    {

    }
    char guessChar = guessStr.charAt(0);
    return guessChar;
}

//remove guess from alphabet
private char[] getCharArray(char[] array)
{
   //this is the part I'm not sure about
}
```

Comment: `I've only created code to search for numbers in arrays before, not chars.` There's really no difference.

Comment: `new String(yourCharArray).contains("" + yourChar)`

Comment: Maybe you should use a `List` instead of an array for this type of code. It lets you delete entries and search for them easily.

Comment: Why not use `String.replace(char, ""');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contains()` method to find the char in the list. Get the char via `char c = guessStr.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[0];` from `guessStr` that player entered. And search it in List via `if (guessedCharList.contains(new Character(c)))`. List can store only objects, so we must convert `char` primitive type to object `Character` via `new Character(c)`.

At the below code will help you! But you should make optimization on it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HangMan {

    private static List<Character> guessedCharList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    private static List<Character> validCharList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    private static String rndWord = null;

    private static int numberOfWrongGuess = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = { "javascript", "declaration", "object", "program",
                "failing" };
        // generate random word from list
        Random rnd = new Random();

        rndWord = words[rnd.nextInt(words.length)];
        System.out.println(rndWord);
        // gets length of generated word
        char[] displayArray = new char[rndWord.length()];
        // displays "_" for number of chars in word

        for (int i = 0; i < rndWord.length(); i++) {
            displayArray[i] = '_';
        }
        char[] alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                +'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                'w', +'x', 'y', 'z' };

        String hangman = null;
        boolean finished = false;
        do {

            hangman = "Let's Play Hangman!!" + "\n" + "-------------" + "\n"
                    + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|"
                    + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "\n"
                    + Arrays.toString(displayArray) + "\n" + "       ";

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    hangman + " " + Arrays.toString(alphabet) + " ");
            guess();

            for (int i = 0; i < rndWord.length(); i++) {

                if (validCharList.contains(rndWord.charAt(i)))
                    displayArray[i] = rndWord.charAt(i);
                else
                    displayArray[i] = '_';
            }

            for (char c : displayArray) {
                if (c == '_') {
                    finished = false;
                    break;
                } else
                    finished = true;
            }

            if (numberOfWrongGuess >= 5) { // 5 wrong guess: "he was hanged."
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Man was hanged!");
                finished = true;
            }
        } while (!finished);

        hangman = "Let's Play Hangman!!" + "\n" + "-------------" + "\n" + "|"
                + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n"
                + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "|" + "\n" + "\n"
                + Arrays.toString(displayArray) + "\n" + "       ";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                hangman + " " + Arrays.toString(alphabet) + " ");
    }

    // get letter
    public static String guess() {
        String guessStr = "";

        while (guessStr == null || guessStr.trim().isEmpty()
                || guessStr.length() > 1) {
            guessStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter to guess: ");
        }

        char c = guessStr.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[0];

        if (guessedCharList.contains(new Character(c))) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(null, "You already give that answer!");
            guess();
        }

        guessedCharList.add(new Character(c));

        if (rndWord.contains(c + "")) {
            validCharList.add(new Character(c));
            return c + "";
        } else {
            numberOfWrongGuess++;
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to put that together. This helped me on so many levels!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is an array cannot change size after it has been initialized. Some solutions would be:

You could use a List (for example java.utils.ArrayList). This way you are able to search and delete entries dynamically.

Another possibility would be to use a character which is not used otherwise, like '-'. Instead of deleting an entry, you replace the character. This way you have to check when accessing the array.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MatchingWordsInStream {
 Map < String, Integer > map;
 String input;
 char arr[];
 int valueArr[];
 StringBuffer stringArr[];
 int space = 1;
 public MatchingWordsInStream(String input) {
  this.input = input;
 }
 public void initialiseCharArray() {
  arr = new char[input.length()];
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
   arr[i] = input.charAt(i);
   if (arr[i] == ' ') space++;
  }
 }
 public void rCharCalculate() {
  stringArr = new StringBuffer[space];
  valueArr = new int[space];
  stringArr[0] = new StringBuffer();
  int index = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { //this loop make string array char
   ch = arr[i];
   if (ch == ' ') {
    stringArr[index] = new StringBuffer();
    ++index;
   } else {
    stringArr[index - 1] = stringArr[index - 1].append(arr[i]);
   }
  }
  for (int k = 0; k < stringArr.length; k++) {
   StringBuffer s = stringArr[k];
   for (int j = 0; j < stringArr.length; j++) {
    if (s.toString().equals(stringArr[j].toString())) {
     valueArr[k] += 1;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 public void result() {
  map = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
  for (int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
   map.put(stringArr[i].toString(), valueArr[i]);
  }
  System.out.println(map);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  MatchingWordsInStream obj = new MatchingWordsInStream("$INDIAN$ wangi bk. wangi bk. 1010 0101 0101 hi hi ii ii ii ii");
  obj.initialiseCharArray();
  //make string to char array
  obj.rCharCalculate();
  obj.result();
  //just for display
 }
}
}
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating two very bad answers you could create one which isn't badly formatted and contains an explanation so it would be (at least) a little bit helpful.